# Static variable is reset to null after a while

Tags: android

I'm creating my first Android app. It is based on GPS tracking. My Android app sends latitude, longitude, and some misc. info (Device ID, Time etc.) to a server. Device ID is stored in a static variable in the Home Activity, and a service is used to send locations. After some time (~25 min.) elapses, this static variable is set back to null. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

One more thing: this app works in the background, i.e. it's not built for continuous use like other apps.

Answer (score 4):

A `static` data member only lives as long as its process does. [Your process will not run forever](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html). Only use a `static` data member as a cache, where the real data is persisted (database, `SharedPreferences`, ordinary file, Internet, whatever), so you can re-initialize your data as needed.